# Ng-if inside ng-template does not work

Tags: angularjs

I created a component and I am trying to make the component's template dynamic, that is, for some condition the parent tag should be a div, otherwise it should be an anchor tag.

I have been trying to use ng-if but somehow it wont work. Here is a code snippet. For some reason, even if the ng-if is true, the nested div (.testDiv .testThumbnail) will be undefined and this will break my component.

I cannot understand why it doesn't find the component even if the ng-if is true. I am new to Angular JS, so maybe I am missing something here? Or there is a better way to dynamically create the component's parent tags according to some condition.

```js
function myCardController($window) {
   var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('.testDiv .testThumbnail'));//is undefined
}

angular.module('myApp').component('myCard', {
 templateUrl: 'testTemplate', ,
 controller: ["$window", myCardController],
});
```

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="testTemplate">
  <div ng-if="true" 
       class="testDiv">
       <div role="img" class="testThumbnail"></div>
  </div>
  <a ng-if="false" class="tesstDiv">same content</a>
</script>
```

Comment: `ng-if` will create its own scope; it doesn't hide your DOM, but removes it completely. Try it with `ng-show` instead, see if you have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss to add *ng-app* or *ng-controller* directive. Use following HTML as your template:

```
<div ng-controller = "myCardController">
  <div ng-if="show" 
       class="testDiv">
       <div role="img" class="testThumbnail"></div>
  </div>
  <a ng-if="!show" class="tesstDiv">same content</a>
</div>
```

Update your JS code as like:

```
function myCardController($window) {
   var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('.testDiv .testThumbnail'));//is undefined
   $scope.show = true;
}

angular.module('myApp').component('myCard', {
    templateUrl: 'testTemplate.html', ,
    controller: ["$window", myCardController],
});
```

You also can use *ng-app="myApp"* in your body tag.